# Why SVG path element is biger than SVG box

Tags: javascript, html, svg

Can you tell my why my path box size is bigger than SVG box size?

Code: 
[https://jsfiddle.net/saj91yjL/](http://Code)

**SVG box size**:

[image]

**PATH box size**:

[image]

You can see that the path box height is bigger than height of SVG. How can I fix it? I want both heights (SVG and path) to be 400 pixels.

Answer (score 1):

Different browsers paint paths differently. The same fiddle which in Chrome shows the path's height to be `405.2px`, in Firefox is ~`400.7px`.

For those who look for a workaround:

```
svg {
   overflow: visible;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Rycerz_Andromedy/saj91yjL/22/)